# Validate a polymorphic model's attribute depending on which model it links to in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Basically, I have three models: a profileable `Profile` model, a `Staff` model and a `Client` model.

If `Profile` model is created for `Staff`, the employee has to be at least 18 years ago. (I use a `validates_date` helper method to check age, see below)
If `Profile` model is created for `Client`, then there is no age restriction.

How to achieve this?

Profile.rb:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
  validates_date        :date_of_birth,    :before => 16.years.ago
end
```

Staff.rb:

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile, as: :profileable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Client.rb:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile, as: :profileable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using conditional validation

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  STAFF = 'Staff'.freeze

  belongs_to :profileable, polymorphic: true
  validates_date :date_of_birth, before: 18.years.ago, if: staff?

  def staff?
    profileable_type == STAFF
  end
end
```